# asp.net gridview: autogenerate buttons on a per-row basis

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Using an asp.net gridview, I can autogenerate edit or delete buttons by setting:

```
myGrid.AutoGenerateEditButton = true
myGrid.AutoGenerateDeleteButton = true
```

Is it possible to enable/disable these buttons on a per-row basis?  If not, is there a way to create a button, maybe in RowDataBound ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you name your Buttons accordingly you can access them inside the RowDatraBound event handler:

```
protected void myGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    e.Row.FindControl("delete_button").Visible = [whatever condition];
    e.Row.FindControl("edit_button").Visible = [whatever condition];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is tap into the RowDataBound event.  Here you can check the condition you are looking for, and then change the button visibility/enabled status.

HTH.